# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined pinch zoom on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gis, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers 3 with google maps. When pinch zooming on mobile, the map stops working and throws an exception:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

```
var googleMapOptions = {
        disableDefaultUI : true,
        keyboardShortcuts : false,
        draggable : false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom : true,
        scrollwheel : false,
        streetViewControl : false
    };
googleMapDiv = document.getElementById('googleMap');
var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(googleMapDiv, googleMapOptions);
openLayersView = new ol.View({
            // Do NOT go beyond the 22 zoom levels of Google Maps
            maxZoom : 22,
            minZoom : 1
        });

        // setting open layer settings
        openLayersMapDiv = document.getElementById('openLayersMap');
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls : ol.control.defaults().extend([ new ol.control.ScaleLine({
                unit : 'degrees',
            }) ]),
            interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({
                altShiftDragRotate : false,
                dragPan : false,
                rotate : false,
                pinchRotate : false,
                mouseWheelZoom:false
            }).extend([ new ol.interaction.DragPan({
                kinetic : null
            }) ]),
            target : openLayersMapDiv,
            view : openLayersView
        });
```

I have seen this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5209 and tried to enable `draggable` but no success.

I am using google maps API 3.2 and openlayers 3.0.0.

I have looked into the problem. On pinch zooming, the zoom value got by `googleMap.getZoom()` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in calling `panTo` on google maps instead I used `setCenter()`.

```
openLayersView.on('change:center', function() {
        var center = ol.proj.transform(openLayersView.getCenter(), EPSG_3857, EPSG_4326);
        //googleMap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(center[1], center[0])); <-- causes the exception
        googleMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(center[1], center[0]));
});
```